# flutter_webview_plugin listener (onHttpError) not working after setstate

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I used `flutter_webview_plugin` and I am changing the screen to show an error message and a reload button using `setState` (this button works on a flag `errorState` that is set by a `onHttpError` listener). When the error occurs it works and shows the error message but when the same error occurs again the listener does not detect the error.

(To reproduce: wifi is on and i open the app, webview loads. Then I press some button on web view to navigate but the error comes up. Now I connect the internet and press the reload button it works and loads the website. After that, I disconnect the internet again and press some button, this time error doesn't show up and goes to Webpage not available)

initial state:

```
  void initState() {
    _onHttpError = flutterWebviewPlugin.onHttpError.listen(
      (WebViewHttpError error) => {
        print("ERROR Listener" + error.toString()),
        setState(() {
          errorState = true;
        }),
        print("error state on listen: $errorState")
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

onReload Method:

```
  void _onReload() async {
    Future<ApiResponse> apiResponse =
        fetchData(widget._username, widget._password);
    var response = await apiResponse;

    print("API RESPONSE =  status: " +
        response.status.toString() +
        ", message: " +
        response.message.toString());

    if (response.status == "true") {
      setState(() {
        flutterWebviewPlugin.reload();        
        errorState = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        errorState = true;
      });
    }
    print("error state on reload: $errorState");
  }
```

Build Method:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("error state on build: $errorState");
    return SafeArea(
      child: errorState
          ? Scaffold(
              body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "No Internet, Please try again.",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _onReload();
                    },
                    child: Text("Reload"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ))
          : WebviewScaffold(
              url: url,
            ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try reloading the webview after the error occurs the first time. Just a thought.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

It has events such as `onLoadError` and `onLoadHttpError`:

- `onLoadError`: Event fired when the WebView encounters an error loading an url.
- `onLoadHttpError`: Event fired when the WebView main page receives an HTTP error.

Here is a quick example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://github.com/flutter",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                      print(code);
                      print(message);
                    },
                    onLoadHttpError: (controller, url, statusCode, description) {
                      print(statusCode);
                      print(description);
                    },
                  ))
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you will receive an HTTP error, the `onLoadHttpError` will be fired and it will print the `statusCode` and the `description` of the HTTP Error.